# Dirichlet's Divisor Function

Tags: analytic-number-theory

We know that by Dirichlet's formula for the Divisor function $ \displaystyle  \sum\limits_{n \leq x} d(n) = x \log{x} + (2C-1)x + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt{x})$.

What is the best approximation available till date for the given formula. I know that finding the infimum of the $\mathcal{O}'s$ is an unsolved problem, but would like to see the closest approximation.

Comment: This question was already asked on MO, I'll try to find it (and close yours afterwards :-( ). You are very-very curious! :-)

Comment: I don't know why should it stay open in this wrong form. ;-) BTW, all question lovers are advised to first visit the OEIS and Wikipedia, before posting their questions. You obviously missed this standard procedure...

Comment: Please make some effort to solve your own curiosity questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_divisor_problem .

Answer (score 2):

you can see also this paper:http://hkumath.hku.hk/~imr/IMRPreprintSeries/2010/IMR2010-10.pdf